Tailwind CSS styles not loading after hard refresh in Next.js 14 with App Router
I'm experiencing an issue with Tailwind CSS in my Next.js 14 project using the App Router. After nav to other route and come back to home page and do a hard refresh of the browser, the Tailwind styles are not being applied to my pages.
tried to make the page client side by adding use client on top the page the issue still the same
Next.js version: 14.2.11 
Tailwind CSS version: 3.4.12 
Using App Router: Yes 
Node.js version:20.10.0
here is my code files
// src/app/page.tsx
    'use client'

     import Footer from "@/components/footer/Footer";
import Header from "@/components/header/Header";
import { GET_All_Courses } from "@/server/API";
import GCard from "@/components/Card/GCard";
import Link from "next/link";
import { COURSES } from "@/server/models/course";

   async function CourseList() {
    try {
        const courses = await GET_All_Courses();

        if (!courses || courses.length === 0) {
            return <h1>No courses found</h1>;
        }

        return (
            <div className="flex flex-wrap gap-4">
                {courses.map((course: COURSES) => (
                    <Link key={course.ID} href={`/course/${course.ID}`}>
                        <div className="hover:cursor-pointer">
                            <GCard course={course} />
                        </div>
                    </Link>
                ))}
            </div>
        );
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error in CourseList:', error);
        return <div>Error loading courses. Please try again later.</div>;
    }
}

export default async function Home() {
    return (
        <>
            <Header />
            <div className="bg-[#F6FCFF] p-4">
                <CourseList />
            </div>
            <Footer />
        </>
    );
}

// src/app/layout.tsx
import "./globals.css";

import { Providers } from "@/context/providers";
import type { Metadata } from "next";
import { Almarai } from "next/font/google";
import { Suspense } from "react";
import Loading from "./loading";

const almarai = Almarai({
  subsets: ['arabic'],
  weight: ['300', '400', '700', '800'],
});

export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: "أكادميه بناء التعليميه",
  description: "أكادميه بناء التعليميه",
};

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: Readonly<{
  children: React.ReactNode;
}>) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body dir="rtl" className={almarai.className}>
        <Providers>
          <Suspense fallback={<Loading />}>
            {children}
          </Suspense>
        </Providers>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}

// tailwindcss.config.js
import type { Config } from "tailwindcss";

const config: Config = {
  content: [
    // "./src/pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
    "./src/components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
    "./src/app/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
    "./src/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
    "./node_modules/@nextui-org/theme/dist/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      backgroundImage: {
        "gradient-radial": "radial-gradient(var(--tw-gradient-stops))",
        "gradient-conic":
          "conic-gradient(from 180deg at 50% 50%, var(--tw-gradient-stops))",
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
};
export default config;

